# Coproduct in the Category of Totally Ordered Groups

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, ordered-groups

This is a question that arised from a problem in valuation theory of commutative rings. There I need to construct a totally ordered Abelian group "containing" every member of a given family of totally ordered groups. Therefore my question is:

Are there (infinite) colimits in the category of totally ordered Abelian groups with increasing homomorphisms?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you assume that the groups are abelian?

Comment: And if not, what is assumed on the order: left-invariant, bi-invariant? (but from the motivation I expect that OP means ordered abelian groups)

Comment: A.A. Vinograd *On the free product of ordered groups* Math. Sb NS **25** (67) 1949, pp. 163-168, MR 11, p 157.  I *think* this was just for a pair, which gives you finitely many; but orderability is “local” (if every finitely generated subgroup is orderable, then the group is orderable), so that suffices. See also George Bergman’s [Ordering coproducts of groups and semigroups](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/papers/ord_cP.pdf).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin [it's "Vinogradov"] this seems much weaker than the required question, which requires the resulting ordered group to satisfy a categorical condition.

Comment: @YCor: But if all that is required is “a totally ordered group “containing” every member of a given family of totally ordered groups”, then you don’t need the categorical property, you just need to be able to order the coproduct.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I had only read what OP calls "my question". To obtain a left/bi-ordered group containing every element $G_i$ of a family of left/bi-ordered groups, the easiest way is to take the direct sum with a lexicographic ordering (wrt a well-ordering of the index set).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are no colimits in general, indeed there is no coproduct for $\mathbf{Z}$ (ordered group) with itself.

There's ambiguity in the question whether the category $\mathcal{C}$ is: ordered abelian groups, left-ordered groups, bi-ordered groups, and whether arrows are supposed to preserve $\le$ or $<$. This gives 6 possibilities; anyway the argument works in all cases. Denote $G_+$ elements $\ge e_G$ or $>e_G$ according to whether arrows are supposed to preserve $\le$ or $>$.

Observe that $\mathrm{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(\mathbf{Z},G)\simeq G^+$ for every $G\in \mathcal{C}$, the identification being given by $f\mapsto f(1_\mathbf{Z})$. Let $H$ be a coproduct of two copies of $\mathbf{Z}$. Then we have two elements $g,h\in H$ such that for every $G\in \mathcal{C}$ the map $\Phi:f\mapsto (f(g),f(h))$ from $\mathrm{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(H,G)$ to $G_+^2$, is a bijection.

Applied to $G=\mathbf{Z}$, choose $f=\Phi^{-1}(1,2)$ and $f'=\Phi^{-1}(2,1)$. 
So $f(g^{-1}h)=1$ and $f'(g^{-1}h)=-1$. Since both $f$ and $f'$ are increasing, we obtain $g^{-1}h>1_H$ and $g^{-1}h<1_H$ respectively, contradiction.

---

(Note: it's not really surprising: in the category of total orders with either $\le$-preserving or $<$-preserving maps, there is no coproduct of the point with itself.)